# java: how to calculate multiplication between all values in variable difference

Tags: java

I received that task:
"A small method, calculateProduct is to be written. It will ask the user to enter two int values, and then calculate and display the product of all the values between the two values entered. For example if the user enters the numbers 2 and 5 the program will display the result 120 (calculated as 2 * 3 * 4 * 5)"

I tried to build something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exam {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a;
    int b;
    int big;
    int small;
    //ask to insert two variables
    System.out.println("Insert variable a");
    a = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println ("Insert variable b");
    b=in.nextInt();
    // compare two variables
    // set the biggest variables to b, the smallest - to a
    if (a >=b){
        big=a;
        small=b;
    }
    else {
        big=b;
        small=a;
    }
    // set the do while loop to complete the code. Run multiplying before counter won't fit to b variable
    int result = small;
    for (int i=small; i<=big;i++){
        result*=i;
    }
    System.out.println("the multiplication progression between "+small+" and "+big+" equals to "+result);

}

}
```

However, when I insert 2 and 5 the result is 240. Does anybody know how to fix it? thanks!

Comment: Initialise `result` as `1` instead of `small`.

Comment: You multiplied the `small` twice.

Answer (score 1):

Change loop to:

```
for (int i = small + 1; i <= big; i++)
{
  result *= i;
}
```

Comment: This is correct. By initializing i = small, you are taking small "inclusive" instead of exclusive in your range.

Answer (score 0):

you init result with small then multiply it by small again.

Fix: Start the for statement with small+1

```
 ...
 int result = small;
for (int i=small+1; i<=big;i++){
    result*=i;
}
....
```

Answer (score 0):

The other obvious solution here is to change the init statement from

```
int result = small;
```

to

```
int result = 1;
```

In that case you don't have to touch your looping code.

And for the record: "small" is a rather bad name here, why not call it "smallerInput" or something like that.

Finally: you could avoid dealing with "small" - if a < b you can simply loop from a to b; and otherwise you could loop "backwards" from "b to a".

Answer (score 0):

Just change your for loop as below mentioned will solve your problem.
The problem in your loop is :

> In its first iteration it is multiple with itself rather than its
>   incremented value.

From:

```
for (int i=small; i<=big;i++)
```

To:

```
   for (int i=small+1; i<=big;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

The task is to write a method called "calculateProduct". Above you are doing all your callculation in your main method. Try to separate that. Example :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exam {

    public static void main (String[]args) { 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a;
        int b;
        System.out.println("Insert variable a");
        a = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("Insert variable b");
        b=in.nextInt();
        if(a>=b){
            calculateProduct(b,a);
        }
        else{
             calculateProduct(a,b);
        }
     }

    public static void calculateProduct (int m, int n) {
        int result = 1;
        for (int i = m; i <= n; i++) {
            result *= i;
        }
        System.out.println("the multiplication progression between "+m+" and "+n+" equals to "+result);
    }
}
```